# jQuery and Ajax: how can i "activate" an event?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm pretty new to jQuery and, for my work, I use to take some JQuery free library and hack them for obtain what I need.

Now I'm in stuck because I have a JQuery that have to do something on page loading, so I use the "classical" JQuery document onload method

```
$(document).ready(function(){
....
}
```

and, of course, that method "load data" once at page first runtime.

Now I have some snippets of code that use Ajax calls for change the page and its content.
So JQuery snippet of code that is included into `ready function` have to be invoked and executed again but that doesn't happen since `ready function` can't be called.

I've tried to google about this, but my little experience, didn't point me to the right place.

So, there is a "standard way" to call my JQuery function **without move Ajax call into JQuery directly**?

Comment: you should provide more code: what did you execute on domready? did you attach some event handlers?

Comment: @F.Calderan what I've asked is what is ... I'm not doing nothing except what I told you into my question. I have an Ajax handler for take care of returned value (of course) and for design the "new page" (again, of course :P). JQuery is only involved onto ready function

Comment: Just a trick, instead of `$(document).ready(function() {});`, you can use `$(function() {});`

Comment: Maybe I misread your question but can't you create your own js file put the code inside a function there and call that function in document ready? This way you can call the function again.

Comment: @sp00m thank you, i'll keep it in mind.

Comment: @Silvermind like F.Calderan says ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I well understood you should refactor your code inside a function, e.g.

```
var codeToBeExecuted = function() {
   /* your code here */
};
```

so when document.ready event occurs just call that function like so

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   codeToBeExecuted()
}
```

and when you perform an ajax call (e.g. using `deferred objects`)

```
$.when($.get(....)).done(function() {
    codeToBeExecuted()
});
```

Comment: Yes, that's seems a good and easy idea. Why dind't my mind suggest that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).trigger("ready");
```